# From the physics standpoint, how should I align a USB Internet stick relative to the nearest cell tower in order to have the best signal?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electronics, electrical-engineering, antennas

I use this USB Internet stick:

[image]

(Huawei E3372h-153)

To connect to the Internet, I simply insert a SIM card into this stick and then insert the stick into a USB port of my laptop.

Based on my experience of participating in Zoom video conferences with this Internet stick, it looks like the quality of the signal depends on the orientation of the laptop (which determines the orientation of the stick because the latter is inserted into a USB port of the laptop), even when the physical location of the laptop remains the same (for example, on the same table in the same apartment).

So, how should I align my Internet stick in order to have the best signal, from the physics standpoint? In the direction of the nearest cell tower? Or perpendicular to that direction? Or maybe at some angle?

I understand that from the practical standpoint, the optimal direction might also depend on surrounding objects such as neighboring buildings and hills as well as the walls of my apartment and even objects inside it. So, I plan to experiment with different orientations and run connection quality tests (ping, download speed, and upload speed), although drawing conclusions won't be straightforward as the signal strength and the connection quality fluctuate with time. The signal strength will go from five bars to two bars and then back to five bars despite the laptop being still, and sometimes the connection gets slow even when I see five bars.

But I am curious about theory. So, assuming there are no obstacles between the cell tower and the laptop with the stick, what should be the best orientation of the stick?

Comment: This might be a better question for [Electronics.SE].

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to say. The unknown geometry of the antenna element inside the stick matters, and the computer and attached wiring are also part of the antenna. The environment is full of reflectors and diffractors, so it's not a clean "wave in empty vacuum". situation.

The resulting link signal/noise will depend on frequency: the cell machinery will try to find the best available frequency.

Answer (score 1):

If connection is bad, the stick comes with an USB-cable for optimal orientation independent of the laptops orientation. If its still bad, there is a jack for an antenna option behind a cap on its side.